# Python not finding modules that I have added to PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, module, pythonpath

My file structure looks like this:

```
main
--src_module
----__init__.py
----utils.py
----tests
------test.py
```

PYTHONPATH looks like: '/Users/myName/main/src_module'

test.py has the line:

```
from src_module.utils import something
```

but when I try to run python test.py, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named src_module.utils
```

I was under the impression that adding the src_module folder to PYTHONPATH would fix this problem, but clearly it hasn't.  Can someone explain to me why I'm still experiencing these import errors?

Comment: Try `/Users/myName/main` instead of `/Users/myName/main/src_module` as your `PYTHONPATH` entry. You want to give the directory that _contains_ your Python packages and modules, not the paths of the packages and modules themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `utils.py` file from tests directory with this structure.

```
main
--src_module
----__init__.py
----utils.py
--tests
----__init__.py
----test.py
```

Also you can use a test runner like nose2 to run your tests with command `nose2` or if you would like to run the `test.py` file by itself then you can run via

```
python -m tests.test
```